# Synchronize between oracle forms and web browser

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have an application built in Oracle web forms 10g.
The users can access the form through a web browser.
In the form, there is a button which calls the function `web.show_documents()`. The function opens an `http` page in another browser window.
I want to be able to know if the new window is still open or it has been closed by the user, because I don't want him to be able to open that http address more than one at a time.

In other words, I would like to disable the button from the moment it was pressed until the new windows (that was created by that button press) is closed.

Is there a way to do it?

I know I can do it by sampling the database constantly, but I would like to avoid this solution because it is resource consuming.

Thanks.

Comment: the web browser is a separate process and is no way connected to forms - I doubt you'll be able to do any such thing

Comment: you may be able to do something with javascript - but this is going to be messy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a parent child window relationship in javascript. In Javascript a child window can be spawned by a parent window in that case the parent window is aware of the child window's `name` and can control its appearance and disappearance (`open` or `close`). However, in this case the parent window spawns the child window but not via `javascript` but using Oracle forms function `web.show_documents`.

Unfortunately, as of Oracle forms 10g there are no other web functions available for you to use (11g has `web.javascript_eval_expr` and `web.javascript_eval_function` which can be used to execute `javascript`).

For a solution- the easiest way would be to use `_self` target name in `web.show_document` instead of default `_blank`. This would make the webpage open in the same browser as of the forms session (in which case you would loose the forms session). You can alert the user notifying of this action saying that its done for `consistency issues` etc. and that the `webpage will be opened in the same window as the forms`.

The other option would be to disable the button altogether (as you said) once the webpage is open. However, a caveat to this would be that the user may close and re-open the form again in which case the button will be enabled (and the webpage may still be open).